# How can I bypass my modem with NAT to open my ports to the outside?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

My Internet provider gave me a Modem-Router with WiFi capabilities but it has all **ports filtered** for incoming traffic. What I'm trying to do is to **use NAT** in someway that allows me **to recieve incoming connections** in some ports.
Incoming connections through NAT are working because uTorrent and other services work fine.

Being the router configuration **locked** by the provider. Is it possible to open my ports?

Comment: What provider? What is the make and model of the modem/router?

Comment: Cablevision Fibertel is the provider and Motorola SBG901 the modem/router.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you would need to do is get into the router to be able to configure your router settings because the Nat settings are in the router. What you can try is to contact the manufacture of the model of your router for example if its a linksys there number is 1 (800) 546-5797 also have you asked your isp for help getting into the router as I have worked with many different Internet service providers and we do not stop you from getting into the router unless this is some new type of ban for torrenting or what knot. can try and check the router for the log in info as well you just go to your web browser and type in the ip address (may be on router along with login) can try the address 192.168.0.1 and also thing is a good reference site:  http://portforward.com/

Comment: Getting into the router configuration is not possible, the provider locks it and configures it automatically through SNMP. I called the provider but the only solution they give me is putting the modem in bridge mode and attaching a router to it (which I have to buy first)